# Importing modules to a package

Tags: python

Is there anyway I can import modules to a package level?

for example, consider the following package:

```
- conf
  - __init__.py
  - general.py
```

Now I have another package:

```
- conf2
  - __init__.py
```

I would like to be able to use `import conf2.general`. That means, somehow importing the general.py module to conf2 package.

---

### EDIT:

I have added the following import to `conf2/__init__.py`:
from conf import general

Now, I can use `from conf2 import general` and it works fine. However, what I would like to achieve is `import conf2.general`. Is that possible?

Comment: I've amended my answer to also answer the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of `conf2/__init__.py`:

```
from conf import general
```

to demonstrate the extra info from the edit, also:

```
import conf.general
```

To demonstrate:

```
$ find .
.
./conf
./conf/__init__.py
./conf/general.py
./conf2
./conf2/__init__.py

$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Aug  2 2010, 20:10:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import conf2
>>> conf2.general
<module 'conf.general' from 'conf/general.pyc'>
```

again, to answer the edit:

```
>>> conf2.conf.general
<module 'conf.general' from 'conf/general.pyc'>
```

Comment: Got it. Is there anyway to make it work with "import conf2.general" ?

Comment: If you use `import conf2.general` then it's imported as `conf2.general`, and that's what it gets called in the module dict. The `from ... import ...` syntax is what you want, I think.

Comment: I do want to import it as `conf2.general`. The problem is that when using `import conf2.general` I get error: "ImportError: No module named general"

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can have some luck with mangling __path__ variable of the conf2 (in the conf2/__init__.py). Here an example where I use PIL.Image instead of conf.general:

```
# from PIL import Image
import PIL
__path__.insert(0, PIL.__path__[0])
```

Still, the whole idea seems odd to me and smells like bad architecture solution unless you are doing something unusual. And all modules of PIL are now in the conf2, not just Image...